# Windows equivalent of /proc/acpi/ibm/light

Tags: thinkpad

I want to the led on my Lenovo Thinkpad- T500 to blink programmatically. I see it can be done in linux by

```
echo "on" > /proc/acpi/ibm/light
```

Is there any equally simple windows alternative for this. I will be really grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arkadiusz Wahlig's](http://arkadiusz.wahlig.eu/Biography.html) command line [ThinkLight.exe](http://files.arkadiusz.wahlig.googlepages.com/ThinkLight.exe) ([C source code](http://arkadiusz.wahlig.eu/download/thinklightlib.zip)) will do it under Windows XP/Vista/7 as long as the Lenovo drivers are installed, no Python required.

```
Usage: ThinkLight.exe <command> [args]
Commands:
  on - turns the ThinkLight ON
  off - turns the ThinkLight OFF
  toggle - toggles the current ThinkLight state
  blink <count> [speed]
    - blinks the ThinkLight <count> number of times,
    - blinks the ThinkLight [speed] times per second, defaults to 3
```

Ref: a [forum.thinkpads.com post](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=70226).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my X230. Not sure if the drivers changed or if it's an issue with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to write a program to do ACPI calls as windows does not expose any of this to the user.

This question would hence be better suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I realize that I should have asked it in Stack Overflow in the first place. I don't think it can be moved now, because my Stack Overflow and Super User accounts are not linked. I'll move it once they are linked. I am user247077 on Stack Overflow.
Meanwhile, this should 
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Python_script_for_Windows_to_control_ThinkPad_features
give an idea to go about solving the problem.